# How to run loop without freezing my app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, for-loop

The loop freezes my app but after it finishes, app works normally. I tried to run loop in `Thread` and it worked very well without freezing app. But now the problem is that I cant run same loop again if I do the app crashes because we cant restart `Thread`. I want to run the loop in a way that it doesn't freezes app and could be run again. How can I do it?

Code in my `MainActivity` class:

```
protected Thread sendthread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 sendthread = new Thread(new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run() {

  for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){

            if  (status == 0){

                break;  

            }

             SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
      sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber.getText().toString(),null,messagetoSend, null, null);

    }

    }
});


}
```

`Thread` is started by a `button`

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        status = 1;
        sendthread.start();

}
```

I stop thread by setting `status` to `0`

Comment: Create new thread for each loop.

Comment: create an `ExecutorService` and run heavy loops there.

Comment: you can use AsyncTask

Comment: If your loop executes for just a few seconds (max 4 sec) then you can use AsyncTask.

Comment: I have tried AsyncTask but no help, Still freezes it could go more then 4 sec depending on user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method as many times you want to loop

```
private void loopInAnotherThread() {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // Your loop
       }
   }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! <3 I was trying to figure out since 2 days.

Comment: @ShahbazTalpur Creating a new thread every time the user presses a button might work in this case, but in general, it is a Bad Idea for a program to create a new thread for each task that it wants to perform in the background.  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  Using an `AsyncTask` (as suggested by Balu SKT) or a thread pool (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`) would be a much better idea.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `AsyncTask`. Start a progressbar in `onPreExecute` function and call `cancel` in `onPostExecute`. Inside `doInBackground` you can call sleep. This will not crash your app and you will not feel like the app is not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Runnable, wich will have the code that loops in its run method. Then make a second Runnable that posts to the UI thread.

```
 Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
 public void run() {
       while (testByte == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 Second delay
            String updateWords = updateAuto(); // make updateAuto() return a string
            myTextView.post(new Runnable() { 
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                      myTextView.setText(updateWords);
                 });
       }
}
```

After that you can create your thread using the Runnable and start it
Like so:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain a boolean variable to control the inner loop and an outer infinite loop to stop thread from terminating.